# C++ Troubleshooting my command line calculator

Tags: c++, calculator

I am using xcode for my c++. It is a simple command line calculator. 
This is what I have so far:

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  test
//
//  Created by Henry Bernard Margulies on 8/21/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Henry Bernard Margulies. All rights reserved.
//
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool loopy = true;  
    cout << "\nCalculator\n";       
    while (loopy == true)
    {
            bool gooy;          
            double answ;            // answer
            double fn;             // first number
            double sn;             // second number
            string opersym;     // operation symbol
            string oper;        // operation
            string more;        // rerun the program or not
            cout << endl << "Operation please (+, - , x or d): ";  //Problem1
            cin >> oper;                                        
            if (oper == "+")                    //makes sure operation is viable
            {
                gooy = true;
            }
            if (oper == "-")
            {
                gooy = true;
            }
            if (oper == "x")
            {
                gooy = true;
            }
            if (oper == "d")
            {
                gooy = true;
            }                                   //does the above
            else                
            {
                cout << endl << "Enter a real operation";       //complains if oper not viable
                gooy = false;
                continue;
            }
            if (gooy == true)                      
                cout << endl << "First number please: ";        
                if(!(cin >> fn))                                //makes sure it is a number
                {
                    cerr  << endl << "Enter a number next time, please try again"; //complaint
                    gooy = false;
                    loopy = true;
                    break;                            //Problem2
                }
                if (gooy == true)     
                {
                    cout << endl << "Next number: ";                                    
                    if(!(cin >> sn))                        
                    {
                        cerr  << endl << "Enter a number next time, please try again";
                        gooy = false;
                        loopy = true;
                        break;                  //Problem2                       
                    }
                    if (gooy == true)
                    {
                        opersym = oper;
                        if (oper == "+")
                            answ = fn + sn;
                        if (oper == "-")
                            answ = fn - sn;
                        if (oper == "x")
                            answ = fn * sn;
                        if (oper == "d")
                        {
                            opersym = "÷";
                            answ = fn / sn;
                        }
                        cout << endl << "You entered: " << fn << " " << opersym << " " << sn << ". And it equals " << answ;
                        cout << endl << "Want more? y/n: ";
                        cin >> more;
                        if (more == "n")
                        {
                            cout << endl << "Okay, I'm not wanted. Shutting down. :(";
                            return(0);
                        }
                        if (more == "y")
                        {   
                            cout << endl << "Back to work!";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cout << endl << "Since you can not be bothered to type it right, I'll take it as a no. :(";
                            return(0);
                        }
                    }
                }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have several requests:

1. First, only division seems to work. Check the first part of main where it asks for an operation and confirms it. It does not want to work for +, - or x, but only for d

2.Check the two comments named problem2. In these parts continue; and break; don't restart the calculator properly. I want to go back to the beginning of the while loop and goto is supposedly unstable and bad.

3.Could you correct my code? I am no expert and the whole thing is very dirtily done. Please show me better logic to make the code shorter, faster and more stable.

Thanks!
ps. I'm a 12 year old kid teaching myself c++ off the internet, so please cut me some slack and explain things like you're speaking to a puppy.

Comment: `goto` is not inherently unstable or bad.  It is simply one of the most misused flow control constructs.  One of the ways to avoid the misuse is to separate your code into smaller functions.  The problem with your `break;` statements that you have labeled as "problem2" is that they should both be `continue;`.  Your first section of `if` statements based on `oper` should use `else if` after the first one until the `else`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the else after `if (oper == "d")` If the operation is not d, the else clause will activate, even if an operation was picked earlier. Try this instead.

```
if (oper == "+")
{
    gooy = true;
}
else if (oper == "-")
{
    gooy = true;
}
else if (oper == "x")
{
    gooy = true;
}
else if (oper == "d")
{
    gooy = true;
}
else                
{
    cout << endl << "Enter a real operation";       //complains if oper not viable
    gooy = false;
    continue;
}
```

Now the final else will only activate, if all previous else clauses were activated.

Alternatively

```
if (oper == "+" || oper == "-" || oper == "x" || oper == "d")
{
    gooy = true;
}
else                
{
    cout << endl << "Enter a real operation";       //complains if oper not viable
    gooy = false;
    continue;
}
```

`break` exits the loop it is in. Try `continue` instead. It goes back to the top of the loop, and if the condition is true, starts over.

Try to declare variables closer to where they are used. For example answ and opersym are not used until late in the loop. You can declare them local to the if statement block for `if (gooy == true)`

Comment: thanks, i understand my first problem. but for my second problem  continue; does not function properly. The output goes all funky

Answer (score 0):

first of all, good luck with learning C++. I am sure you'll pick it up in no time at all :) Here's a basic calculator. It's not ideal but shorter.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    using namespace std; //use namespace only within the scope of main()

    //ask user to choose operation
    string operation = "";//good to initialize local variable. otherwise C++ assigns them garbage values
    while(operation != "+" && operation != "-" && operation != "*" && operation != "/")
    {
        cout << "Please enter a mathematical operation. Options are: + or - or * or /" << endl;
        cin >> operation;
    }
    cout << "You entered " <<  operation << endl << endl;

    //ask user to enter two numbers
    double number1 = 0, number2 = 0, result = 0;
    bool success = false;//true if calculation carried out successfully

    //keep looping till calculation carried out successfully
    while(success!=true)
    {
        cout << "Please enter the first number: " << endl;
        cin >> number1;
        cout << "Please enter the second number: " << endl;
        cin >> number2;

        if(operation == "+") result = number1 + number2;
        else if(operation == "-") result = number1 - number2;
        else if(operation == "*") result = number1*number2;
        else if(operation == "/" && number2 != 0) result = number1/number2;
        else 
        {
            cout << "Please enter non-zero value for number2 since carrying out division" << endl;
            continue;
        }
        success = true;
        cout << "Result is: " << number1 << " " << operation << " " << number2 << " = " << result << endl;
    }
    return(0);
}
```